# if $\log M=m$ and $\log N=n$, in terms of $m$ and $n$, simplify: $\log{\left(\frac{1}{M}+\frac{1}{M}\right)(N+M)^{-1}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> If $\log M=m$ and $\log N=n$, in terms of $m$ and $n$, simplify: $\log{\left(\frac{1}{M}+\frac{1}{M}\right)(N+M)^{-1}}$

**BTW:** the answer is supposed to be -m-n

---

I have attempted to solve this in multiple ways in which I have become stuck:

**Method 1:**

$\log{((\frac{1}{M}+\frac{1}{N})^2)}$

which becomes $\log{(\frac{1}{N^2}+\frac{2}{MN}+\frac{1}{A}})$

from this method it seems to be impossible because inside of the fraction there are addition signs and makes it hard to split up the log expression

**Method 2:**

$\log{((\frac{1}{N}+\frac{1}{M})*(\frac{1}{N}+\frac{1}{M}))}$

which then becomes  the following:

$2\log{\frac{M+N}{MN}}$

which becomes  the following:

$2\log{M+N}-\log{MN}$

which also gets me stuck becomes the addition sign makes it impossible to split them up.

I there fore request assistance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\log\left(\dfrac{\frac{1}{N}+\frac{1}{M}}{N+M}\right)
&=& \log\left(\dfrac{\frac{N+M}{NM}}{N+M}\right) \\
&=& \log\left(\dfrac{1}{NM}\right) \\
&=& -\log\left(MN\right) \\
&=& -\log M - \log N \\
&=& -m-n
\end{array}$$

---

### Notes

It looks like you are not familiar with the rules of logarithm:

- $\log(ab) = \log a + \log b$
- $\log\left(\dfrac ab\right) = \log a - \log b$
- $\log(b^n) = n\log b$
- $\log_ab = \dfrac{\log_n b}{\log_n a}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(\dfrac1M+\dfrac1N\right)(N+M)^{-1}=\dfrac{N+M}{NM}\cdot\dfrac1{N+M}=\dfrac1{NM}=(NM)^{-1}$$

$$\log\left\{\left(\dfrac1M+\dfrac1N\right)(N+M)^{-1}\right\}=\log\{(NM)^{-1}\}=-\log(NM)$$

Now, $\log(NM)=\log N+\log M$